# TortoiseSVN connect via ssh: Network connection closed unexpectedly

Tags: windows-7, ssh, tortoise-svn

I am trying to connect to an SVN repos via the svn+ssh protocol on Windows7 (32-bit). I have the server set up fine and can connect from my Linux box. When trying to connect from my W7 machine (I have Putty, Plink, Pageant and TortoiseSVN all installed), it tries to connect 3 times and then gives me this error

```
To better debug SSH connection problems, remove the -q option from 'ssh' in the [tunnels]
section of your Subversion configuration file.
Network connection closed unexpectedly
```

Looking at the server logs I can see my SVN user log in 3 times via SSH and I can use Putty to log in using my account and private key using "pure" SSH. I'm more familiar with Linux than Windows so not sure how to debug this any further.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

What I did with TortoiseSVN is:

- try disconnecting your network, you will be asked to take tortoise offline, choose offline mode
- do a cleanup
- connect your network and try updating...

That solved a same problem for me...